# Select menu php sorting

Tags: php, sorting, select, drop-down-menu

[image]
I'm experiencing a few problems here. I'm trying to get my select menu to sort the php elements in the right hand side of the image above, however I can't seem to get it to recognize the change.
I have tried using

```
 if (isset($_GET['col'])){
            $sortcolnum = $_GET['col'];
            } else {
            $sortcolnum = 0;
            }

        if (($sortcolnum >= count($cols)) || ($sortcolnum < 0)){
        $sortcolnum = 0;
```

but I'm not sure how to add that on to the random clause i have set up already.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT id, name, category, description, price, thumb, large FROM '.$this->table_name.' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4'); 
            $stmt->execute();
            //send info back to where readAll() was called
            return $stmt;
     }//end readAll();
```

I've tried adding the where clause but it still won't take.
The main image is also being loaded through the GET function as well.

here's the code of the main page, with a few different attempts of sorting.

```
   <div class="left-img">

       <div class="dropdown-description styled-select">

        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">
        <select id="CategorySelect" onChange="this.form.submit();">

         <option value='all_cakes'>-- Pick a category --</option>

         <option value='Wedding'>Wedding cakes</option>

         <option value='Birthday'>Birthday cakes</option>

         <option value='rightside.php?col=3'>Cupcakes</option>

         <option value='rightside.php?col=4'>Specialty sweets</option>

         <option value='rightside.php?col=5'>Traditional</option>

         <option value='rightside.php?col=6'>Modern</option>

         <option value='rightside.php?col=7'>Themed</option>

         <option value='rightside.php?col=8'>Festive</option>

        </select> 

    </form>
        </div>
<?php





while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

 if(isset($_POST['CategorySelect']) )
{
 $row['category']= $_POST['CategorySelect'];

}else{
    echo 'not set';
}

?>



<div class="element  hvr-grow">



<a href="description.php?detailsid=<?php echo $row['id'];?>"> <img class="imgurmob" src="img/<?php echo $row['category']; ?>/<?php echo $row['thumb']; ?>" </a>



  </div> 


        <?php 

}

?>
```

Comment: give this a name attribute `<select id="CategorySelect" onChange="this.form.submit();">` in regards to the POST array `$_POST['CategorySelect']`. as in `<select name="CategorySelect" id="CategorySelect" onChange="this.form.submit();">` you should be getting an undefined index notice here. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I don't seem to have been getting an error. I have error_reporting(E_all) turned on and the others. but i did add the clause as suggested regardless.

Comment: you're using JS with this and have not included it in your question. You might want to add it. Look at your console also. Nothing more that I can do here. Maybe somebody else will pick up on something I can't see.